# Python objects sharing information

Tags: python

I have a workflow that parses a url and loadsdata.

The flow is controlled through URLProcessor.

In this current setup I'm passing the url variable across all classes just to display the process start and completion of process. I feel its redundant information. 
Is there a way to share the url variable across all objects instead of explicity passing it.

```
class ParseURL(object):
    def __init__(self, url):
        self.url = url

    def parseoperation(self):
        print 'start operation for url {0}'.format(self.url)
        pass
        print 'end operation for url {0}'.format(self.url)
        return None

class LoadData(object):
    def __init__(self, url, data=None):
        self.url = url
        self.data = data

    def load_operation(self):
        print 'start operation for url {0}'.format(self.url)
        pass
        print 'end operation for url {0}'.format(self.url)


class URLProcessor(object):
    def __init__(self, url, parseurl, loaddata):
        self.url = url
        self.parseurl = parseurl
        self.loaddata = loaddata

    def run(self):
        print 'start operation for url {0}'.format(self.url)
        self.parseurl.parseoperation()
        self.loaddata.load_operation()
        print 'end operation for url {0}'.format(self.url)

url = 'http://test.com'
parseurl = ParseURL(url)
loaddata = LoadData(url)

urlprocessor = URLProcessor(url, parseurl, loaddata)
urlprocessor.run()
```

Comment: Since `url` being common to three of the classes, why don't you create a `base` class with that attribute and derive others from it?

Comment: Passing an object to other objects is a way of sharing it. It you always pass the same object there is no redundancy.

Comment: @SijanBhandari: How can I do that? still when I initialize each object, the url needs to be passed, correct?

Comment: Unlike "pure" OO languages like Java, in Python not every function has to be in some class. Here, you can just have three standalone functions: `process_url`, `parse_url` and `load_data`. The fact that your class names start with verbs is a hint in this direction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simple solution here would be to pass `url` to the 'xxx_operation' method calls instead of passing them at instanciation:

```
class URLParser(object):
    def parse_operation(self, url):
        print 'start operation for url {0}'.format(url)
        print 'end operation for url {0}'.format(url)
        return None

class DataLoader(object):
    def __init__(self, data=None):
        self.data = data

    def load_operation(self, url):
        print 'start operation for url {0}'.format(url)
        print 'end operation for url {0}'.format(url)


class URLProcessor(object):
    def __init__(self, url, urlparser, dataloader):
        self.url = url
        self.urlparser = urlparser
        self.dataloader = dataloader

    def run(self):
        print 'start operation for url {0}'.format(self.url)
        self.urlparser.parse_operation(self.url)
        self.dataloader.load_operation(self.url)
        print 'end operation for url {0}'.format(self.url)

url = 'http://test.com'
urlparser = URLParser()
dataloader = DataLoader()

urlprocessor = URLProcessor(url, urlparser, dataloader)
urlprocessor.run()
```

Now as Thomas mentions in a comment and judging only on this hopefully abridged snippet, you don't seem to really need classes here:

```
def parse_url(url):
    print 'start operation for url {0}'.format(url)
    print 'end operation for url {0}'.format(url)

def load_data(url, data=None):
    print 'start operation for url {0}'.format(url)
    print 'end operation for url {0}'.format(url)

def process_url(url, parse_url, load_data, data=None):
    print 'start operation for url {0}'.format(url)
    parse_url(url)
    load_data(url, data)
    print 'end operation for url {0}'.format(url)

url = 'http://test.com'
process_url(url, parse_url, load_data)
```

Remember that in Python everything (well, statements excepted) is an object, including functions, classes and modules. If you find yourself writing a class with one single method, chances are you want a function instead. Also remember that you can define your own callables (defining the `__call__(self, ...)` method on your class) so a class or method expecting callbacks can be passed not only functions but just any callable - ie if you find out you'd rather implement `load_data` as a class for readability or any other reason, you can still do it without changing `process_url()`:

```
class MyDataLoader(object):
    def __init__(self, db):
        self.db

    def _do_something(self, args):
        pass

    def _do_something_else(self, args):
        pass

    def __call__(self, url, data):
        print 'start operation for url {0}'.format(url)
        self._do_something(url)
        self._do_something_else(data)
        print 'end operation for url {0}'.format(url)


url = 'http://test.com'
db = MyDB.connect(connectioninfos)
load_data = MyDataLoader(db)
process_url(url, parse_url, load_data)
db.close()
```

Comment: CUrrently, these objects has only one function but in the future it will end up having multiple functions, thats the reason I have it as separate objects rather than functions.

Comment: @user1050619 is this a certain and very near future or a "I think that perhaps at some point in the future I might add other methods" future ?-)